# after removing element from dom the length property doen't reflect that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html created on the fly with javascript:

```
<div class="panel panel-default theaterPlayer">
<div class="panel-body  panelbody69875341">
<div class="paneltop paneltop69875341">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove close closePlayer"></span>
</div>
<iframe width="560px" height="340px" id="id69875341" 
        src="" style="margin- top: 50px;"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Then when i hit the closePlayer button in Jquery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.closePlayer', function(event) {
$(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('.theaterPlayer').remove();
});
```

Then when i want to now the length off the element with class theaterPlayer so i know how much off those elements exist:

```
$('.theaterPlayer').length;
```

shows the ones removed + 1

How can i remove from the dom AND remove from that other collection that seams to exist?

Comment: `$(this)` refers to what? what does the `$(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove();` remove?

Comment: ever heared of an element that you click with an id that you can refer to as this? And further... it does get removed from the dom cause i can SEE that. The length property however doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @ingridsede Just checked with the jsfiddle - shows length = 0. Are you sure your $(this) points exactly to the span.closePlayer?
https://jsfiddle.net/rna8y6ku/ - check console

Comment: yes i know what `this` is but you have not posted the whole code. we don't know where the code `this` is located?

Comment: this is how the fuction looks like: $('body').on('click', '.closePlayer', function(event) {

$(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('.theaterPlayer').remove();

});

Comment: why dont you just use `$(this).closest('.theaterPlayer').remove();` ?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x9evuxx3/

Comment: @ingridsede your function works fine https://jsfiddle.net/rna8y6ku/1/

Comment: I think you have cached `var players = $('.theaterPlayer')` and trying to access its `length` w/o quering the DOM. jquery wrapper is not live. If you need live collection you can use native `var players = document.getElementsByClassName('theaterPlayer');`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rna8y6ku/2/)

Comment: Indeed i can see in your fidles that it does what it should do. I'm using the exact same code in my project and it keeps adding +1. Bizar! i'll look further.

Comment: @ingridsede can you create an [MCVE]? If we had more code, we may be able to help you, but as you can see, we are all pretty much guessing what your problem is

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact that the creation of the element is done from within an iframe in the parent? A piece of the code from the iframe: var panel = parent.document.createElement('div');
  panel.setAttribute('class', 'panel panel-default theaterPlayer');

Answer (score 0):

May be the number of `div` changes at runtime. try removing it like:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.closePlayer', function(event) {
$(this).closest('.theaterPlayer').remove();
     });
```

Comment: I should be realy very ashamed of myself!!! Appendeing it to .container wasn't a smart thing to do because i'd forgotten i use another element with the same class that was'nt visible  so i didn't noticed it. I'm very sorry for wasting all you time!

Answer (score 0):

Using this

```
$(".closePlayer").closest('div').parent('div').remove();
console.log($('.theaterPlayer').length);
```

Now you are able to remove all the inner `div`s, which contains in the outer `div` which has class `panel panel-default theaterPlayer`. So here i am assuming that on fly you are appending html to the `div` which contains class `theaterPlayer`:
Hence,

```
$('.closePlayer').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('div').parent('div').remove(); // Here removes all inner Divs
    console.log($('.theaterPlayer').length); // Length will be 1, and Outer Div remains there.
});
```

Or if u want remove all the `div` including outer `div` on Clicking of Close button, then use simply

```
$(this).closest('div.theaterPlayer').remove(); //Removes all given(html) Div's and show length as 0;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The .theaterPlayer is created with javascript from within an iframe in the parent. All that's inside is also created with javascript. This all get appended to a .container element that already exists in the dom.  Tried $(this).closest('div.theaterPlayer').remove();  and similor approaches but still +1 every time

Answer (score 0):

I should be realy very ashamed of myself!!! Appendeing it to .container wasn't a smart thing to do because i'd forgotten i use another element with the same class that was'nt visible so i didn't noticed it. I'm very sorry for wasting all you time!